# Setting product option default values in Product detail page

Tags: product, custom-options

I would like to set default values to product options in product page. I then defined on observer called by `catalog_product_load_after`

My observer.php is called as I use it also for a setFinalPrice function and it works.

But, I do not manage to access the product options…

```
public function preconfandprice($observer)
 {
   $_product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    ...
   $_options = $_product->getOptions();
 }
```

returns an empty array…

Comment: what are the attributes you want to set to a default value ?

Comment: it is not attribute, but custom options, text type, called height and width. May I use attribute instead?

Comment: each products have attributes (height, width) and attributes can have options (1cm,2cm...). Are these attributes used to create configurable products ?

Comment: I sell custom made products, which price depends on the dimensions. The dimensions can be freely chosen by the customer. I have a quotation form computing the price of the product according to the chosen dimensions/parameters. I then would like to display the product page with preconfigured options.

Comment: I think you'd better do that with javascript/prototype but I am not super confortable with that. With observer, it can be possible but I cannot find the good function to set the default.

Comment: the button of my quotation form used to call my product page is linked to a controller. The easiest way would be to set the product option from this controller before loading the product page as it can access to all the form variables… Passing the variable from the controller to the observer is another blocking point to me...

Answer (score 1):

You can auto-select configurable product options using an URL params:
For example:

http://demo.magentocommerce.com/men/new-arrivals/khaki-bowery-chino-pants.html#92=17

Where 92 is the color attribute ID and 17 is the color value ID.